# Eclipse crashes on renaming

Tags: eclipse

I am new to Eclipse using Eclipse Luna on GNU/Linux with

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime=2
org.eclipse.platform=4.4.0.v20140606-1215
```

in my 'version.ini' and

```
 -startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
 -product
 org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 -showsplash
 org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256m
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.appendVmargs
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
```

in eclipse.ini.

Whenever I want to rename a class and often when I rename a variable, Eclipse crashes/exits instantly and I can find no information in `workspace/.metadata/.log` as only runs of Eclipse which is closed down properly seem to be logged (The last time stamp appearing in the log will always be older than the start of the crashing run).

Are there other log files I can look for information on what is happening?

In another post with Eclipse crashing under different circumstances, it was suggested to add `-clean` when starting up Eclipse. This hasn't changed anything for me.

EDIT:

I have

```
 # Problematic frame:
 # C  [libcairo.so.2+0x68c21]  cairo_surface_set_user_data+0x11
```

in the `hs_err_pid` file.

Comment: Try to find crash dump file of the JVM (file named `hs_err_PROCESSID.log`). This file is either located in Eclipse root directory or your home directory. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html#gbwcy

Comment: You might also want to check system logs (e.g. `/var/log/kern.log`). If the process was killed by OS (SEGFAULT or by OOM Killer), some message should be there.

Comment: Ok. I get  #Problematic frame: # C  [libcairo.so.2+0x68c21]  cairo_surface_set_user_data+0x11 in the hs_err file.

Comment: What kind of Linux distribution you have and what is your desktop environment?

Comment: I use Crunch Bang which is essentially Debian 7.0. Openbox is the window manager.

Comment: Seems like problem with SWT. I suggest you to create a bug report in [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) (don't forget to attach the hs_err file).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this and other Eclipse issues like [Bug 401717](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401717) simply following [this procedure:](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=115477#p545781)

> Try this, first do:
>
> `export SWT_GTK3=0`
>
> and then start eclispe.
>
> If it works, a permanent option:
>   you can add the following lines to eclipse.ini to make it permanent
>
> `--launcher.GTK_version
>       2`
>
> This will force eclipse to use GTK 2 always

Add those lines before `--launcher.appendVmargs`.

EDIT: I'm using Crunchbang too.

Comment: I just posted a more detailed [comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442223#c5) on bugzilla.